# How to make SSL cover 2 WordPress installations in different directories under 1 main domain

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, subdirectory

I plan to buy a multi-domain SSL. My site is www.example.com (Wordpress install)

www.example.com/blog (WordPress install no. 2)

Under this setup of 2 WordPress installs, will the SSL cover both main and sub-directory? I am using multi-domain as I have another e-commerce site.

I am afraid if there will be any conflict in the WordPress for using SSL in this way. My host uses SNI and cPanel.

Can anyone please let me know how to set this up?

Comment: www.example.com/blog and www.example.com are the same domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have nothing to worry, if both are under the same domain just in different directories they will both be covered by a regular SSL, if they are under sub-domains (ex: domain.com, and shop.domain.com) then you would need 2 SSLs or a wildcard SSL

Comment: I am getting a multi-domain ssl and thanks a looot for the confirmation :)